# Google Apps Script error: "You do not have permission to access the requested document"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, spreadsheet, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to create a function in the Google Spreadsheet for my coworkers to input the data in the spreadsheet, then click on the "Send" button to achieve the following tasks:

1. Manually input data is linked to another sheet (Invoice template), so the apps script is set to generate the other sheet (template) into pdf file
2. The pdf file will be sent out automatically using their individual gmail account
3. The pdf file will also be automatically stored in a designated folder in Google Drive

This is my first time using Apps Script. I found a set of script from a website and used it for my Spreadsheet. It worked perfectly with my account, but when my coworkers tried to execute it, it showed this error message: `"Exception: You do not have permission to access the requested document. at emailInvoiceAsPDF(Invoice:10:29)"`

Below is the script that I used for my spreadsheet:

```
 /**
   * @NotOnlyCurrentDoc
   */

function emailInvoiceAsPDF() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();
 /**
   * @NotOnlyCurrentDoc
   */
  // This is the link to my spreadsheet with the Form responses and the Invoice Template sheets
  // Add the link to your spreadsheet here 
  // or you can just replace the text in the link between "d/" and "/edit"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pzKLOSnKt2NNCOL8-mG1YVgELp8Hf-v9PhMkSI-YYte/edit");

  // We are going to get the email address from the cell "B7" from the "Invoice" sheet
  // Change the reference of the cell or the name of the sheet if it is different
  const value = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice Template").getRange("J32").getValue();
  const email = value.toString();

  var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Invoice template');
  var subject = sheet1.getRange("B2:N2").getValue();

  // Subject of the email message


  // Email Text. You can add HTML code here - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  const body = "Dear customer,<br><br> Please find the attached Invoice. <br><br> Thank You.";

  // Again, the URL to your spreadsheet but now with "/export" at the end
  // Change it to the link of your spreadsheet, but leave the "/export"
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pzSZZSnKtPPieRL8-mG1YVgELp7Jv-v9PhMkSI-AeZA/export?';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf
    '&size=letter' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    '&scale=4' +
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid=196383625'; // the sheet's Id. Change it to your sheet ID.
  // You can find the sheet ID in the link bar. 
  // Select the sheet that you want to print and check the link,
  // the gid number of the sheet is on the end of your link.
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // Generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // Send the PDF file as an attachement 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: "Invoice" + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });

   // Save the PDF to Drive. The name of the PDF is going to be the name of the Company (cell B5)
   const nameFile = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice Template").getRange("B2").getValue().toString() +".pdf"
   var Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("12oHonHMo0ZBS-qZkxe1Iuyfm5miy0fXQ");
  Folder.createFile(response.setName(nameFile))
}
```

I tried reading a lot of threads on Google but I have no clue to resolve this problem. I am very frustrated... Please help..

Comment: It looks the file you are trying to access in line 10 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl... is shared with your account, but not shared with your coworkers accounts.

Comment: Hi Milan, Thank you for your response. The file in line 10 is shared with my coworkers, and they have already obtained authorization for using the script. Do you think I should create deployment in order for my coworkers to use it?

Comment: Double check the sharing settings of the Sheet, and also try using a different sheet which is publically available for testing purporses.

Comment: Elizabeth, is it shared in View only mode?

Comment: Hello, the file is shared with all coworkers, everyone is Editor for this file. I am trying to build a new spreadsheet using the same script to see if it can be solved.

Comment: Do you still experience this problem? Might be due to beimng signed in with multiple acounts.

Comment: Hi, are you still experiencing this?

Comment: I have tried this and it did work for me, the only issue I faced is that the "coworker" had to get access to the spreadsheet and to the folder used in the script. Have you tried to share the folders used and the ones that contain the sheet and script with editor access to the coworkers?

Answer (score 1):

Giving the users access to all the files and folders used in the script does not throw the error.

If the user does not have **Editor** access to the folder where the PDF is to be stored or to other folders/files involved in the script, this error will happen.